# Mongodb retrieve records - missing name after . operator

Tags: mongodb

The frontend application create collections and create records put into collections.  How can I retrieve records from a collection.  why the collection created with a bunch of numbers and letter. The Error shows SyntaxError: missing name 
after . operator @(shell):1:3

```
> show collections
04a4e6b8-381e-40ff-81aa-fa872b08b801_bags
04a4e6b8-381e-40ff-81aa-fa872b08b801_rankings
04a4e6b8-381e-40ff-81aa-fa872b08b801_sets


>db.04a4e6b8-381e-40ff-81aa-fa872b08b801_bags.find()
 2019-01-30T12:56:24.397-0500 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError:  @(shell):1:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [db.getCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/):

```
db.getCollection('04a4e6b8-381e-40ff-81aa-fa872b08b801_bags').find()
```